# How to display 4 co-ordinate GraphView in android

Tags: android

i get error at

```
    GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
        new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
        , new GraphViewData(2, -1.5d)
        , new GraphViewData(-3, 2.5d)
        , new GraphViewData(-4, -1.0d)
    });

    GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
        this // context
        , "GraphView" // heading
    );
    graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumVerticalLabels(5);
    //graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsWidth(300);
    graphView.setManualYAxisBounds(5,1);


    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.addView(graphView);
```

I want to draw the line for all four co-ordinates.. but the negative points does not work..
help me

iwant like this

stack trace

```
09-01 04:17:53.299: I/Process(2263): Sending signal. PID: 2263 SIG: 9
09-01 04:17:54.149: D/AndroidRuntime(2302): Shutting down VM
09-01 04:17:54.149: W/dalvikvm(2302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3afcba8)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302): Process: com.jsk.simplegraph, PID: 2302
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jsk.simplegraph/com.jsk.simplegraph.SimpleGraphMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The order of the values is not correct. X-Values have to be ordered ASC. First the lowest x value and at least the highest x value.
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The order of the values is not correct. X-Values have to be ordered ASC. First the lowest x value and at least the highest x value.
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries.checkValueOrder(GraphViewSeries.java:200)
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302):     at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries.<init>(GraphViewSeries.java:74)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: i couldn't understand ur ques

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Read this Q&A for the steps to start solving your problem. In particular, it shows how to view the stacktrace and figure out which line of code causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack message is quite clear:

```
The order of the values is not correct. X-Values have to be ordered ASC. First the lowest x value and at least the highest x value.
```

So, you should initialize `exampleSeries` the following way:

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(-4, -1.0d),
    new GraphViewData(-3, 2.5d),
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d),
    new GraphViewData(2, -1.5d)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

read the stacktrace

```
09-01 04:17:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(2302): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The order of the values is not correct. X-Values have to be ordered ASC. First the lowest x value and at least the highest x value.
```

try this

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(-4, -1.0d),
    new GraphViewData(-3, 2.5d),
    new GraphViewData(2, -1.5d),
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
});
```